# Bitnami rails docker container: wkhtmltopdf:55:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, wkhtmltopdf, bitnami

I'm trying to convert an existing app into docker using bitnamis official rails image. I'm using `wkhtmltopdf` for PDF generation. It is working witout docker container but inside docker container I'm getting this error.

```
Failed to execute:
["/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "--encoding", "UTF-8", "--zoom", "2", "--dpi", "1000", "--page-width", "12in", "--page-height", "7.6in", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20210523-1-1tprbwc.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20210523-1-ket44c.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
Command Error: /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.5/bin/wkhtmltopdf:55:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.5/bin/wkhtmltopdf_debian_10_amd64 (Errno::EACCES)
from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.5/bin/wkhtmltopdf:55:in `open'
from /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.5/bin/wkhtmltopdf:55:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/wkhtmltopdf:23:in `load'
from /opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/wkhtmltopdf:23:in `<main>'
```

The docker compose yml file is

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes

  myapp:
    tty: true # Enables debugging capabilities when attached to this container.
    image: docker.io/bitnami/rails:6
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - DATABASE_NAME=my_app_development
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

The link to the official docker image is: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/rails/

When done some research found out we need to change the permissions with `chown` but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Do you have your own Dockerfile?  Does the `wkhtmltopdf` binary actually exist in your image?

Comment: no I do not have the original dockerfile. I’m using the original compose file which is autogenerated while we install from that official link. I have added only pdf libraries gems. I do not know what else needs to be done. I have very little knowledge in docker containers.

Comment: The Docker documentation includes a tutorial with a [sample application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/); while it's Node-oriented, it includes all of the steps of building and running a custom image.  That will usually be a better practice than trying to use an unmodified language-runtime image and injecting your code into it.  (rbenv or rvm could be a better match if you want a development environment, but isolated from the system Ruby and other applications.)

Comment: @DavidMaze it worked when I entered into the docker console and executed `sudo chmod -R 777  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/` . Do you know how this can be set up in a compose file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created `Dockerfile` and customised the image and it worked. The only problem currently is I need to set up the permissions every time I take builds.

**`Dockerfile`**

```
FROM docker.io/bitnami/rails:6
RUN sudo apt update
RUN sudo apt install wget xfonts-75dpi -y 
RUN cd 
RUN sudo apt -y install wget
RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb
RUN sudo apt install ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb -y
#RUN sudo chown -R bitnami:bitnami /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/
ENV RAILS_ENV="production"
```

**`docker-compose.yml`**

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3
    environment:      
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw

  myapp:
    tty: true # Enables debugging capabilities when attached to this container.
    #image: docker.io/bitnami/rails:6  
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - DATABASE_NAME=my_app_prod     
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw 
      - RAILSENV=production
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

It works but after I take builds I need to execute

```
docker-compose exec myapp sudo chown -R bitnami:bitnami /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/
```